# Cache-control set to 8 hours from Java end is getting overridden by no-cache from server

Tags: cache-control, jboss6.x, http-status-code-304, no-cache, max-age

I am using below code to add cache-control for static files.

```
 public void setContentType(String type) {
        if (type.startsWith("text/html") || type.endsWith("text/xml")) {
            // For HTML and JSF files, no caching
            super.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
            super.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        } else if (type.startsWith("text") || type.startsWith("image")) {
            // For text and image files, cache for 8 hours
            super.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + EIGHT_HRS_IN_MILLIS);
            super.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=28800");
            super.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        }
    
        super.setContentType(type);
    }
```

Initially it works fine and fetch from memory cache, but after some time it gives 304 error code and cache-control changes to no-cache.
Which is causing slowness in loading the static content.

I tried with private window and localhost it works fine.
When I deploy the code to jboss server the issue occurs, looks like no-cache is added from server end.

How to keep 8 hours cache-control and not to override by no-cache.